# Cannot delete LXC container with full volume nor the volume itself

Tags: lxc, btrfs, lxd

I've been toying around with LXC/LXD lately and ended up with a couple of stopped containers:

```
❯ lxc list
+------------------------------------+---------+------+------+-----------+-----------+
|                NAME                |  STATE  | IPV4 | IPV6 |   TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+------------------------------------+---------+------+------+-----------+-----------+
| build                              | STOPPED |      |      | CONTAINER | 0         |
+------------------------------------+---------+------+------+-----------+-----------+
| build-2020-05-27-180024-06f86fd0ac | STOPPED |      |      | CONTAINER | 0         |
+------------------------------------+---------+------+------+-----------+-----------+
```

Time to clean up:

```
❯ lxc delete build
Error: Error deleting storage volume: Failed deleting subvolume "/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/build": Failed to run: btrfs subvolume delete /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/build: ERROR: cannot delete '/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/build': No space left on device
```

```
❯ lxc storage info default
info:
  description: ""
  driver: btrfs
  name: default
  space used: 970.61MB
  total space: 1000.00MB
used by:
  containers:
  - build
  - build-2020-05-27-180024-06f86fd0ac
  images:
  - 40775fd923e2a77f56ce3c028ce22ad43b9254bb12766b12eeeefb32a3a145da
  profiles:
  - default
```

Apparently the volume is too small. My naive approach to solve this was to increase the volume size from `1G` to `10GB` via `lxc storage edit default`. As there is no obvious way to apply the changed setting I trust it's applied automatically by `lxc storage edit` . Turns out it isn't (as reported by `lxc storage info default` afterwards).

Next try: Let's just delete the insurgent volume so I can delete the container:

```
❯ lxc storage volume list default
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+
|   TYPE    |                               NAME                               | DESCRIPTION | USED BY |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+
| container | build                                                            |             | 1       |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+
| container | build-2020-05-27-180024-06f86fd0ac                               |             | 1       |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+
| image     | 40775fd923e2a77f56ce3c028ce22ad43b9254bb12766b12eeeefb32a3a145da |             | 1       |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+
```

```
❯ lxc storage volume delete default build-2020-05-27-180024-06f86fd0ac
Error: not found
```

Now I'm a bit stuck. What options do I have to delete the container (or resize the volume - which in turn shoud allow deleting)?

---

**Update 1:** Here are some specs about the system used.

```
❯ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

```
❯ snap list | grep lxd
lxd    4.1    15161    latest/stable    canonical*        -
```

---

**Update 2:** In the meantime I tried to resize the volume "manually", like this:

```
truncate -s +500G /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/disks/default.img
mount -t btrfs /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/disks/default.img /mnt/test
sudo btrfs filesystem resize max /mnt/test/
reboot # because why not, hopfeully lxd catches up
```

After the reboot I could successfully delete both, the image and the volumes.

Everything looked good at this point. When I created a new container however, it refused to erase it with the same symptoms as described above. Same for the volume.

According to `lxc storage show default` the upgrade to 10G has been recognized by lxd after the reboot. I don't think it is possible the 10G capacity has actually been reached.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: Hmmm. I ran out of space similarly using ZFS (not btrfs) a couple months ago. However, I don't understand why LXD refuses to simply delete a container (I could). I wonder if it's a btrfs feature?